# Keep common rows within every group of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following pandas data frame:

```
  | a  b
--+-----
0 | 1  A 
1 | 2  A 
2 | 3  A 
3 | 4  A 
4 | 1  B 
5 | 2  B 
6 | 3  B 
7 | 1  C 
8 | 3  C 
9 | 4  C
```

If you group it by column `b` I want to perform an action that keeps only the rows where they have column `a` in common. The result would be the following data frame:

```
  | a  b
--+-----
0 | 1  A 
2 | 3  A 
4 | 1  B 
6 | 3  B 
7 | 1  C 
8 | 3  C
```

Is there some built in method to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) here then filter using [`sreries.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
s = df.pivot_table(index='a',columns='b',aggfunc=len).dropna().index
df[df['a'].isin(s)]
```

Similarly with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['a'],df['b'])
df[df['a'].isin(s[s.all(axis=1)].index)]
```

---

```
   a  b
0  1  A
2  3  A
4  1  B
6  3  B
7  1  C
8  3  C
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the purpose of `aggfunc=len`? It is always so difficult to wrap your head around how to wrestle the pandas api to get what you want :)

Comment: @MartinRindarøy when using a pivot table, we have to use a aggregate function, I used length (`len`) here to get the size of each group per the values of column a. Then dropped wherever there is a `NaN` since they are not present in every group

Comment: Ah, I see. Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a better title of this question btw? Really difficult to come up with a clear title.

Comment: @MartinRindarøy *keep common rows within every group*? :) its hard to find a suitable title always

Comment: @anky_91 in your crosstab solution do you really need the .ne(0) I think not. And can you change all(1) into the more readable all(axis=1)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df2=df.groupby("a")["b"].nunique().eq(len(df.groupby("b").groups))
df=df.merge(df2.loc[df2].rename("filter"), on="a").drop("filter", axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
   a  b
0  1  A
1  1  B
2  1  C
3  3  A
4  3  B
5  3  C
```

Answer (score 4):

one liner using `transform` and `groupby` with boolean filtering and `dropna`

```
df[df.groupby(['a'])['b'].transform(len).eq(df['b'].nunique())].dropna(how='all')
print(df)
   a     b
0  1    A 
2  3    A 
4  1    B 
6  3    B 
7  1    C 
8  3    C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the intersection between all groups and use it for filtering:

```
from functools import reduce

intersect = reduce(np.intersect1d, df.groupby('b')['a'].apply(list))
df.loc[df['a'].isin(intersect), :]
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  A
2  3  A
4  1  B
6  3  B
7  1  C
8  3  C
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no entries with a and b the same this should do it

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,3,4],'b':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C']})
uniques_b = len(df['b'].value_counts()) # target number of unique entries
counts_a = df['a'].value_counts()
desired_in_a = counts_a[counts_a.values==uniques_b] #find only those values in a that are there for every value in b
df_pruned=df[df['a'].isin(desired_in_a.index)] #keep only those columns which have matching entries in a
```